# Why openssl s_client verifies a cert against a mismatching CAfile?

Tags: openssl, certificates, gnutls

I am trying to yield a certificate verification error with `openssl s_client` like this:

```
$ openssl s_client -crlf -verify 9 \
  -CAfile /etc/ssl/certs/TURKTRUST_Certificate_Services_Provider_Root_1.pem \
  -starttls smtp -host mx-ha03.web.de -port 25
```

The certificate of the web.de server is certified by the Deutsche Telekom CA, not TURKTRUST, thus the above command should fail, right?

But it reports:

```
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
```

Why?

I mean an analog gnutls-cli command fails as expected:

```
$ { echo -e 'ehlo example.org\nstarttls' ; sleep 1 } | \
   gnutls-cli --starttls --crlf \
   --x509cafile /etc/ssl/certs/TURKTRUST_Certificate_Services_Provider_Root_1.pem \
   --port 25 mx-ha03.web.de
[..]
*** Verifying server certificate failed...
```

Doing a crosscheck, i.e. using instead `--x509cafile /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt` with gnutls-cli I get:

```
[..]
- The hostname in the certificate matches 'mx-ha03.web.de'.
- Peer's certificate is trusted
```

(which is also expected)

Openssl s_client prints for ca-certificates.crt:

```
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
```

The same result as for TURKTRUST ...

First I suspected openssl using a default setting for `-CApath` (i.e. /etc/ssl/certs) - but when I `strace` the process I just see just the `open` syscall for the argument of `CAfile`.

(all tests done on a Ubuntu 10.04 server)

**Update:** I've copied the TURKTRUST certificate to a Fedora 20 system and executed the first openssl statement - there I get a different result:

```
Verify return code: 19 (self signed certificate in certificate chain)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It turns out that the `openssl s_client` on Ubuntu 10.04 still queries a default location for system installed certificates, even if `-CApath` **and** `-CAfile` are specified:

```
8466  open("/usr/lib/ssl/certs/4e18c148.0", O_RDONLY) = 4
```

(strace output)

Where:

```
$ ls -l /usr/lib/ssl/certs/4e18c148.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 30 2014-04-11 21:50 /usr/lib/ssl/certs/4e18c148.0 ->
    Deutsche_Telekom_Root_CA_2.pem
```

The directory `/usr/lib/ssl/certs` is a symlink to `/etc/ssl/certs` on Ubuntu 10.04, thus the `open` line from the strace log is not selected when grepping for '/etc/ssl' ...

### Source

Looking at the openssl-0.9.8k, the source of this issue is located in `crypto/x509/by_dir.c`, `dir_ctrl()`:

```
dir=(char *)Getenv(X509_get_default_cert_dir_env());
if (dir)
    ret=add_cert_dir(ld,dir,X509_FILETYPE_PEM);
else
    ret=add_cert_dir(ld,X509_get_default_cert_dir(),
                     X509_FILETYPE_PEM);
```

Where `X509_get_default_cert_dir` returns `/usr/lib/ssl/certs` and `X509_get_default_cert_dir_env` returns `SSL_CERT_DIR`.

### Workaround

Thus, one can use following workaround under Ubuntu 10.04/openssl 0.9.8k to get the expected behavior:

```
$ SSL_CERT_DIR="" openssl s_client -crlf -verify 9 \
    -CAfile /etc/ssl/certs/TURKTRUST_Certificate_Services_Provider_Root_1.crt \
    -starttls smtp -host mx-ha03.web.de -port 25
```

And with the verification fails:

```
Verify return code: 19 (self signed certificate in certificate chain)
```

### Current Situation

This is a Ubuntu issue. For example, with the Fedora 20's openssl 1.0.1e or Fedora 29's openssl 1.1.1, this workaround is not necessary, because the issue cannot be reproduced. That means when specifying an option like `-CAfile` or `-CApath`, no default certificate system directory is added to the directory search list on Fedora systems.

On Ubuntu 16 with openssl 1.0.2g the issue is still present.

It's also present on CentOS 7 with openssl-1.0.2k-16 - and unfortunately, the above workaround doesn't help there and the gnutls-3.3.29-8 fails due to unknown/unexpected TLS packet types.

Comment: I have version 1.0.2g and it still has this bug. To make things worse, the -verify_return_error flag has no effect whatsoever and the TLS connection proceeds even if the cert is wrong.

Comment: @takumar, I re-tested this under Ubuntu 16 with openssl 1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.14 and I can confirm, without the workaround this openssl test still fails. But at least with the workaround I get the expected error message  - and with the workaround and `-verify_return_error` the command terminates with exit status 1. With Fedora 29 and openssl-1.1.1-3.fc29.x86_64 everything still works as expected, i.e. the workaround isn't necessary.

Comment: In 2019, this still seems to be the case on macOS. Also, some systems might support `-no-CAfile` (_Do not load the trusted CA certificates from the default file location_) and `-no-CApath` (_Do not load the trusted CA certificates from the default directory location_), but my system does not, so I've not tested those.

Comment: @takumar it seems that you can get `-verify_return_error` to work if you also specify `-verify <depth>` - the manpage says about `-verify`: "This specifies the maximum length of the server certificate chain **and turns on server certificate verification**. Currently the verify operation **continues after errors** so all the problems with a certificate chain can be seen. As a side effect the connection **will never fail due to a server certificate verify failure**."